# Why do Buddhism monk hits people in the head?

Tags: monk

i saw this video on facebook and youtube ,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHDp1GbzE4o

and they're writing on it in arabic 
"الرقية الشرعية عند البوذيين "
witch means "the buddhism's Exorcism" 
i want to know if this is really a buddhism exorcism . if not , what is it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's a usual practice. I found [this explanation](http://www.khaosodenglish.com/life/2015/06/09/1433853163/) online:

> A monk who was seen forcefully hitting temple-goers' heads with a bundle of dried grass has defended the unorthodox practice, calling it his unique way of blessing the faithful.
>
> Phra Jirapan Analyo, the 53-year-old abbot of Pha Sadej monastery in Saraburi, admitted that the practice may look violent in a video that went viral this week, but insisted that it does not hurt.
>
> "The knocking of heads is a way to cure diseases and illness for the faithful," Phra Jirapan said. "And the knocking may look violent, but it didn't hurt anyone."
>
> ...
>
> Phra Benja Papassaro, a monk who oversees temples in Saraburi province, told reporters that he watched the video and believes "his action does not violate the holy doctrines, though it does look excessive." He said he and other senior monks are discussing the issue to find a formal conclusion on the matter.

A more usual form of Thai "blessing" would be "sprinkling" water ([see for example here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/9172/254)).

Answer (score 0):

No, they are neither Disciples of the Buddha nor do they care about the conducts of the Noble ones (Althought not having looked the movie), if socializing in such ways and touch even lay people.

Touching a living being in aversion, beating, is a violation of the precepts. Touching a living being out of lust, for socialising purpose is a violation of the precepts.

Touching the head of others is very respectless, it migh be out of this, that people show in this way there respect, a cultural costum.
For Tibetans for example very usual, but again, it's not the costum of the Noble Ones and has nothing to do with Brahmacaria (holly life)

And to do such as "Exorcism", if that was the case, that is not only simply betray but called "livelyhood like animals" and not allowed to do for laypeople generally like a "doctor".

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma not meant for commercial purpose or other wordily gains]*

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this monk is Not practicing correctly irrespectively of whether he defend his action. Even you can chase evil out it is not Buddha practice, try find the chapter to convince me.